# Error 400 : Missing Client_ID for Google oAuth2

Tags: google-oauth

I have added Client_ID in application.Properties file and HTML file but still Google shows Error 400: invalid request, Missing Client_ID.
Here is relevant HTML Code Snippet for the same:

```
<div class="hero-content">
      <h1>Welcome to BITSbids</h1>
      <p>Discover amazing products at fascinating prices</p>
        <a href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
  client_id=792979004767-5fvs24lfomcue1h532sqdluskt60ieql.apps.googleusercontent.com
  &redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google
  &response_type=code
  &scope=openid%20email"
           class="cta-button">Get Started</a>
    </div>
```

Here is relevant JS code snippet:

```
// Assuming you have a route for handling user authentication
app.post('/auth/google', (req, res) => {
  // Validate Google Sign-In token and get user information
  const user = validateGoogleToken(req.body.token);

  if (user) {
    // Generate a session token
    const sessionToken = generateSessionToken(user);

    // Redirect the user to the user page
    res.redirect(`/user/${user.id}`);
  } else {
    // Handle authentication failure
    res.status(401).send('Authentication failed');
  }
});
```

And, relevant application.properties file:

```
ogging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE
spring.security.oauth2..client.registration.google.client-id=792979004767-5fvs24lfomcue1h532sqdluskt60ieql.apps.googleusercontent.com

spring.security.oauth2..client.registration.google.client-secret=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
```

I have tried multiple ways to rectify the issue, from generating new OAuth2 Credentials, to changing Redirect URLs, and to changing SecurityConfig file.
As I am a begineer in the field, any help would be greatly appreciated.